# Roomba 500 Series - Raw encoder counts readings

Tags: roomba, quadrature-encoder

I have been trying to read Roomba raw encoder counts I am receiving values, but I have a sudden increase/decrease in values as can be seen over here.

142 152

153  166

167  180

181  196

50101  33280

207  223

222  238

236  252

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
// Roomba Create2 connection
int rxPin = 10;
int txPin = 11;
SoftwareSerial Roomba(rxPin, txPin);
void setup() {

pinMode(10, INPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Roomba.begin(19200);
  delay(1000);
    Roomba.write(128);  //Start
  Roomba.write(132);  //Full mode
  delay(1000);
}
char command;
void loop() {



  if (Serial.available()){
    command=Serial.read();} 
switch (command)
  {   
    case '8':
  Roomba.write(byte(145));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  Roomba.write(byte(0x28));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  Roomba.write(byte(0x28));
  delay(50);
  encoder_counts();
  break;
  case '0':
    Roomba.write(byte(145));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  Roomba.write(byte(0));
  break;
  }
}



void encoder_counts()
{
   unsigned int  right_encoder;
    unsigned int   left_encoder;
   byte  bytes[4];   

  Roomba.write(byte(149)); 
  Roomba.write(byte(2));
  Roomba.write(byte(43));
  Roomba.write(byte(44));
  delay(50);
   int i=0;
while(Roomba.available()) { 
  bytes[i++]=Roomba.read();
left_encoder = (unsigned int)(bytes[0] << 8)|(unsigned int)(bytes[1]&0xFF); 
right_encoder =(unsigned  int)(bytes[2] << 8)|(unsigned int)(bytes[3]&0xFF);
}  



Serial.print(right_encoder);
Serial.print("  ");
Serial.println(left_encoder);

}
```

so please kindly advice, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to *Robotics*, Ahmed. You have posted the code you use to *build* the encoder counts, but not the code you used to *display* the counts. I mention this because you have the encoder counts displayed in your post as:

> 13786.00 13938.00

as in, *with a trailing decimal*, but your encoder counts are defined in your code to be *integers*. This could be problematic if the `print` function is treating your two-byte integer as the *first* two bytes of a floating point number.

The second issue it looks like you've got is that you're defining your encoder variables as `int` instead of `unsigned int`. Per [the manual](https://www.irobot.lv/uploaded_files/File/iRobot_Roomba_500_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf),

> encoder [count] is returned as an unsigned 16-bit number, high byte
>   first

Try redefining your `right_encoder` and `left_encoder` as `unsigned int`, and then also try changing the formatting in your `print` command to something like `Serial.print(right_encoder)` instead of `Serial.print(right_encoder, 2)`.

If that doesn't work, please *edit your question* to post the code you're using to display the values.

Comment: first of all, I really appreciate your time in replying to my post. Thank you! thank you so much for pointing out the correct manual to use, I have been using completely different manual mentioning it returns signed values from -32k to 32k.     Now I edited the question with the code I'm using